# Hadoop hdfs cluster to be configured on mounted disk rather than default disk

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

OS: Ubuntu
I am trying to configure hadoop(2.7.2) cluster on mounted disk instead of default disk. Mounted disk is '/mnt/raid' and have performed following configuration in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///mnt/raid/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///mnt/raid/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

But, when I start dfs(start-dfs.sh), I dont see namenode and datanode. I am not able to figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking your permissions in /mnt/raid/hdfs. If they are not open to reading and writing, etc, the namenodes and datanodes won't start. This issue can be confirmed by checking the logs for both. If you do need to change permissions $cd /mnt/raid/hdfs, then $chmod 777 *. Also, be sure /mnt/raid/hdfs/datanode and /mnt/raid/hdfs/namenode exist. Hope that helps.